# If column value is null, use other column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, csv

First of all, don't scold me for trying to do this - my boss wants me to dump a list of data from across many tables into a single CSV file.

This CSV contains two categories of people combined into a single sheet: *permanent staff*, and *contractors*.

Some values are obtained differently depending on which category you belong to. For example, if you are a *contractor*, your job description is in `contractors.blended_role`. If you are *permanent*, the job description is in `roles.blended_role` where `roles.id = staff.role`.

So I tried (something like) this:

```
SELECT
    stuff,
    (CASE
        WHEN c.blended_role IS NULL THEN
            r.blended_role
        ELSE
            c.blended_role
        END) as `Job Description`,
    morestuff
FROM
    everyone e
LEFT JOIN contractors c
    ON c.id = e.id
LEFT JOIN staff s
    ON s.id = e.id
LEFT JOIN roles r
    ON r.id = s.role
```

But I got a syntax error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'stuff, (CASE WHEN c.blended_role IS NULL THEN r.blended_role EL` at line 2
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative?

#### Update

The syntax error was from a missing comma a couple of lines up.

Comment: please post the error you got

Comment: You should post the exact error. For a start, I think the table aliases in your CASE structure should be `c` and `r` instead of `cv` and `rv`.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: @Vimsha The actual error contains the real column names that I don't want you to know - I'll post an equivelant error to what I got.

Comment: @vollie If you know the answer, write an answer, not a comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have no table aliases called `rv` and `cv`.  Perhaps you mean:

```
SELECT
    (CASE
        WHEN c.blended_role IS NULL THEN
            r.blended_role
        ELSE
            c.blended_role
        END) as `Job Description`
```

Or, more simply:

```
coalesce(c.blended_role, r.blended_role) . . .
```

Comment: Sorry, yes, I use 'rv' and 'cv' in the real SQL. I'll try coalesce!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use

```
SELECT
    stuff,
    ifnull(c.blended_role,r.blended_role) as `Job Description`,
    morestuff
FROM
    everyone e
LEFT JOIN contractors c
    ON c.id = e.id
LEFT JOIN staff s
    ON s.id = e.id
LEFT JOIN roles r
    ON r.id = s.role
```

Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull for more info.